# Why is the associated type not allowed in this case?

Tags: rust

```
trait Envs {
    type Item;
    type Iter: Iterator;
    fn get_envs(&self) -> Self::Iter<Item=Self::Item>;
}
```

I am trying to implement the method that returns the environment variables but I couldn't figure out why the associated type is not allowed in the trait.

Answer (score 4):

```rust
trait Envs {
    type Item;
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;
    fn get_envs(&self) -> Self::Iter;
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b15f2f913e3cd29890e4f6a64a7443d4)

If you do like above, it would restrict the implementer of the trait to specify an `Iterator` which has an associated type same as `Envs::Item`. So, `Envs::Item` needs to be same as `<Envs::Iter as Iterator>::Item`.

---

If you do like:

```rust
trait Envs {
    type Item;
    type Iter: Iterator;
    fn get_envs(&self) -> Self::Iter;
}
```

This would allow the implementer to specify an `Iter` which doesn't return elements same as `Envs::Item`. So, in this case it could be possible that `Envs::Item` was `i32` but the `Envs::Iter` is an `Iterator` over `String`.

Comment: There is also the option of making just the method contingent on the extra requirement: `fn get_envs(&self) -> Self::Iter where Self::Iter: Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;`. (Not very useful in this case, but useful when one method has stronger requirements than the rest of the trait, and the trait is usable without it.)

Comment: Yet another option is not bothering with declaring `Item` as an associated type, and just declaring `type Iter: Iterator;`. You can still access the item type using `Self::Iter::Item` if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the trait method return a boxed Iterator trait object like below if you meant to have the associated type of the iterator to be the Item associated type of your trait.

```
trait Envs {
    type Item;
    fn get_envs(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item=&Self::Item>>;
}
```